# Change Combobox Caret Icon Size in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have created a simple form using bootstrap 3 framework. Now I want to increase the size of combo-box caret icon(which is shown in picture) from select box.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here it is my code

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <select class="form-control input-lg" id="">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

how can i change this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRRhT.png

Answer (score 1):

use following css property:

```
 select {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      /* Some browsers will not display the caret when using calc, so we put the fallback first */ 
      background: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") white no-repeat 98.5% !important; /* !important used for overriding all other customisations */
      background: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") white no-repeat calc(100% - 10px) !important; /* Better placement regardless of input width */
    }
```

Comment: it works joshi. but I want to change only icon. while using your code, that gray color border goes to transparent..

Comment: Okay, then use only background property.

Comment: I tried. but it filled full area. of select list. any way thanks for the reply. i'm waiting for some reply. if I didn't get any response, i will approve your answer.